# Removing app from Profile

Tags: facebook

I have an old app I created along time ago in my business time line profile - I can't find how to remove this - any pointers?

Thank you.

Jonathon

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to remove **facebook** application from your profile?

*if yes:*

Account Settings > Apps > Select app, click the X next to edit, delete all app activity > Click remove

*if no:*

edit your question, its unclear

Answer (score 0):

Because Business accounts can't manage apps, it seems you're in a catch-22 position where the app is still linked to your account but inaccessible.

Add another (real user, verified with SMS or credit card) via the API and have that user delete the app. Provided you authorise your app with the business account via the Oauth dialog, you can use the admin's access token to add additional admins.

The method for doing so is outlined on the ['Application' documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) - you make a HTTP POST request to the 'roles' connection of the App using  with the parameters app_id, user and 'role'  - set 'role' to 'administrators' to add an admin with the ability to delete the app