# Adjust a Facebook app that was created on a normal account which is now a 'Ads account'

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

When going to the 'apps' link in the topmenu on http://developers.facebook.com, it always redirects me to the Ads Management page. I closed my Ads-account 1 week ago, but this does not help. It's really annoying b/c I can't manage or add any apps now.

I have already understood that it's due to the fact that the apps were created when my account was still a 'personal' account and once I started to use the Ads in Facebook, it was switched into a 'Ads account'. 
(see also: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8507163/redirection-to-campaigns-facebook-ads-page-why)

But, now that I want to adjust the apps that I have previously created, how can I do that?

Comment: Related:  http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account

Though i think there is a way using the business account to add additional admins via the api, let me try find the answer i posted before

Comment: Ah, yes, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12007596/21062

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was actually hoping that you as a FB-dev would pick up my question ;) In the suggested link, you talk about 'deleting' the app, but what we want to do is actually 'edit' the app settings. Can this also be done through the way you describe?

And also: would you, as FB-dev, be able to change the user account back to a normal account (instead of a Business/Advertizer account? This would save a lot of hassle.

Thx, Jonathan

Comment: To delete the app, that user needed to add a new admin, so just don't delete the app once you've added the additional admin

Comment: hi again, the thing is: if you want to use the API solution that you mentioned, you need the APP id + the Access Token. Now the access token is only known when logging into the app settings. So I'm still in the loophole. So without knowing the Access Token, it's not possible to solve the issue, right?

Comment: No, you log into the app using the login flow from the documentation - business accounts can still use the API, they just lack many of the same fields and connections as user accounts, but you should be able to change the app settings using a user access token for your app

Comment: Yeah but that's the thing :) I don't have any user access token of this app. And the only way to get hold of this token is via the app settings which I cannot reach. Or am I incorrect and is there a way to get hold of the token?

Comment: No, you don't need to get to the app dashboard to create an access token for an account; you use the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) process to do that, in the same way you log in your app's regular users  except that when you do so as the account which is an admin of the app, you can use the resulting access token to access the API and add other admins

Comment: We have created some code as follows: http://hastebin.com/rovayutuga.html

Using the console and FB.api('commandgoeshere', somehandler), I have inferred that the business account that made the app doesn't in fact currently have admin access (The Graph API docs told me to check /me/accounts, which I did - it returns an empty array). 

Am I going wrong here somehow?

Comment: `/me/accounts` is for pages, look at the answer i added, you should be looking at the Application object docs and checking the 'roles' connection

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) process with the business account, in the same way you log in your app's regular users

Once you've done this as the account which is an admin of the app, you can use the resulting access token to access the API and add other admins.

Provided you authorise your app with the business account via the Oauth dialog, you can use the admin's access token to add additional admins.

The method for doing so is outlined on the ['Application' documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) - you make a HTTP POST request to the `roles` connection of the App using  with the parameters app_id, user and `role`  - set 'role' to 'administrators' to add an admin with the ability to delete the app